# Usage of gridlelayout within scrollview

Tags: android, gridle

hi I create an activity with relative layout/scrollview/gridlelayout but my application didnt open. what is my mistake? is not gridlelayout use within scrollview?
hi I create an activity with relative layout/scrollview/gridlelayout but my application didnt open. what is my mistake? is not gridlelayout use within scrollview?

thanks alot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.peg.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:rowCount="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/s"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@drawable/s" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/hur"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:background="@drawable/hur" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mil"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@drawable/mil" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ysr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ysr" />
        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please add your stacktrace here.

Comment: please check my below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

you increase the `android:columnCount="2"` and `android:rowCount="2"` in Gridlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:rowCount="2">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/s"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/hur"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

             <Button
                android:id="@+id/mil"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ysr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: When I delete background image everything is ok. but I have to add background image what can I do?

Comment: @a.alld please check image in your **drawable** folder.

Comment: I try it I guess we couldnt add background image on gridlelayout. thanks alot  to your interest.

Comment: @a.alld Welcome, Happy to help you.

Comment: thanks could you any knowledge about my last question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378997/adding-mp3-file-on-recyclerview     thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in items count You have 4 buttons but only one row and only one cell, try with:

```
   <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2">
```

I would advice you to use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) if your view get more complicated.

Comment: When I delete background image everything is ok. but I have to add background image what can I do?

Comment: Did you try to add background to the RealtiveLayout

Comment: I try it I guess we couldnt add background image on gridlelayout. thanks alot  to your interest.